# Do Flash heads only work with DSLR cameras?

Tags: lighting

I have a non-DSLR (originally I had the 5D MKII) camera and have a bunch of flash heads that I want to use to shoot some quick but professional portraiture shots for friend.

Are these compatible with non-DSLR cameras? and if not, is there a way to cheat and use them anyway?

Comment: Can you be more specific (make/model) on "flash heads" and "non-DSLR camera"? That could mean almost anything from a Canon speedlight to Novotron pack and heads; and a film large-format view camera to a mirrorless or P&S. Please edit your question text to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the ways you can trigger the "flash heads" and the options your camera gives you (hotshoe, sync port, pop-up flash) to trigger them. Also the age of the flash heads and the sync voltage they use.

Mirrorless cameras (if that's what you're using) can have widely ranging sync voltage limits. I've heard everything from 5V to 250V.  But vintage lights can sometimes sync far above that.  So, testing your lights to see what the sync voltage is might be a good idea, if they're old vintage lights.  Newer digital-age lights tend to sync below 10V and should be safe.

Most studio strobes have optical slave capability, so as long as your camera has a pop-up flash or you have an on-camera flash (speedlight) you can attach to your camera's hotshoe, you can probably trip the heads. The main issue will be whether you can turn off any metering preflashes for TTL that the pop-up flash may issue.  Most typically, you have to put the on-camera unit into M mode, but in the case of FUJI, they designate a preflashless mode to the built-in flashes as "commander" mode (this is confusing, because Nikon also uses commander mode to mean a "smart" optical slave master mode which emits multiple preflashes [facepalm]).

If the camera has a hotshoe or PC sync port, things can get even simpler. You can cable the flash directly to the sync connector for the heads.  Purchasing a hotshoe-to-sync adapter will take care of any lack of a sync port on the camera.

If you're talking about something like a Godox AD200, however, that bare bulb flash has a built-in radio trigger that can system switch between Canon, Nikon, Sony, Fuji, and micro four-thirds.  So you just need to get a radio transmitter that matches your new "non-DSLR" camera's system, and you'll be in full radio control over the light again.

So, no, off-camera flashes don't only work for dSLRs.  But whether your specific gear will work with the specific camera you have, and with what function, will depend on the sync options both offer. Typically, most wireless flash gear that can perform TTL/HSS with Canon gear will not do so with non-Canon gear.  Newer systems from the last year or so (Nissin Air, Godox X, Profoto Air, Cactus V6II, and Jibei/Orlit RT) can do system switching, but if your gear is older than this, it probably can't.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a digital camera with a Hot-Shoe. Any such camera will work with a typical flash-head. Nearly every mirrorless also has a hot-shoe but those will not save you much money when compared to a DSLR, so instead you can look at fixed lens cameras.

[This search on Neocamera](https://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?hotshoe=1&lensattachment=fixed) shows there are currently 23 fixed-lens cameras with a hot-shoe. In case you didn't guess from my avatar, this is my own site and the result is live, meaning anytime you follow this link you will get the latest set of cameras for the given search. Feel free to use the column on the left to refine results further.

Alternately, you can use a flash head remotely with a camera that has a built-in flash (and possibly no hot-shoe) by using a an Optical Slave Trigger. This is a tiny device with its own hot-shoe and a light detector. When it detects the on-camera built-in flash firing, it triggers the flash head that is attached to it. Those can cost as little as $10 USD. The downside is that the on-camera flash must fire too and it must manage to illuminate the Optical Slave Trigger, so you are not completely free to position it.